# How to create a layout as per the figure attached supporting multiple selection of grids?

Tags: android, android-layout

I would like to create this kind of UI with the data coming from the server.
Assume we have list of US states abbreviations coming from server into an a string array.

[image]

I implemented this using gridView and added an adapter to the view to fit the US state abbreviations. Now the thing I need add functionality in SearchBox. Whenever I type in AL or any text, the grid layout should display only the items starting with AL.

Comment: Can be closed under the official close reason of "too broad": _Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer_.

Answer (score 0):

You can create view dynamically anyhow.

See [this Example](http://www.warriorpoint.com/blog/2009/07/01/android-creating-tablerow-rows-inside-a-tablelayout-programatically/). Where TableLayout is generated programmatic. Based on that you can also create the Button like forward, Go and Next to the same layout.