# Application throws null pointer exception when we try to capture selected checkbox ids on submit button in Android

Tags: android

I have a grid layout with a EditText field on the top of the screen. I am implementing base adapter to fill in the value for grid layout.

The code I am using is as follows. My main activity

```
public class MainActivityDynamic extends Activity{

GridView gridView;
GridObject[] planets;
ArrayList<GridObject> myObjects;
Button Go;
ImageAdapter adapter;
int position;
boolean[] itemChecked;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.gridlayout);
    Go = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bGO);
    gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gV); 
    String[] primarycontext =  {"first","second","third","fourth","fifth","sixth","seventh","eighth","ninth","tenth","leventh","twelth","thirteenth","fouteenth","fifteenth","sixteenth","seventeenth","eighteenth","nineteenth","twenteth","twentyfirst","twentysecond", "twentythird","twentythird","twentyfouth"};

    gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this, primarycontext));
    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new GridView.OnItemClickListener(){

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position,
                long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //myObjects.get(position).setState(1);
            //myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "clicked on "+position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    });


    Go.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            int len = 10;
            int cnt = 0;
            String selectImages = "";
            for (int i = 0;i<len; i++){
                if (adapter.itemChecked[i]){
                    cnt++;
                }
            }
            if(cnt == 0){
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "please select atleast one", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else
            {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "you have selected" + cnt + "boxes", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            String item = (String) adapter.getItem(position);
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "selected fields"+item, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    }

}

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
    Context mContext;
    public ImageAdapter(Context c,String[] primarycontext)
    {
        mContext = c;
    this.primarycontext = primarycontext;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return providers.length;
    }
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return primarycontext[position];
}
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View v;
    if(convertView==null){
    LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) mContext
        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    v = new View(mContext);
    v = li.inflate(R.layout.icon, null);
    }
    else
    {
     v = convertView;  
         }
        ImageView iv = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_image);
    iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.folder_0);
    CheckBox CBx = (CheckBox)v.findViewById(R.id.cBIon);
    CBx.setText(primarycontext[position]);
        CBx.setChecked(isItemChecked(position));   
        return v;
    }
private boolean isItemChecked(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("the returning items="+itemChecked);
    return itemChecked;
}
}
}
```

In the main layout I have a gridview occupied with a checkboxes with text and an Image. I have a Submit(Go) button which when clicked should capture all names of the checked boxes checked in main activity. How can I do that? When ever I run this code and click on Go, the application crashes and returns null pointer exception.

Errors

```
11-25 05:43:50.390: E/AndroidRuntime(519): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-25 05:43:50.390: E/AndroidRuntime(519): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-25 05:43:50.390: E/AndroidRuntime(519):  at com.example.kam1.MainActivityDynamic$2.onClick(MainActivityDynamic.java:73)
11-25 05:43:50.390: E/AndroidRuntime(519):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
11-25 05:43:50.390: E/AndroidRuntime(519):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
11-25 05:43:50.390: E/AndroidRuntime(519):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not see you initialize `adapter` variable anywhere. Replace this:

```
gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this, primarycontext));
```

with

```
adapter = new ImageAdapter(this, primarycontext);
gridView.setAdapter( adapter );
```

Also do not use `getBaseContext()`. You should use `MainActivityDynamic.this` instead.

And it looks you use Toast for debug purposes - I'd suggest to switch to `Log` ([see docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html))

Comment: Yup I understand. I tried to debug the null pointer thing and found that it customadapter class returns null into main activity. If you look at these lines of code for (int i = 0;i<len; i++){
                if (adapter.itemChecked[i]){
                    cnt++;
                }, I am being returned null here. Can you please get me to a point where I have to return the tags of the checkboxes checked into a string

Comment: I worked. The app doesn't crash now. Can you give me few minutes to quickly work on the remaining process of returning the tags for the selected checkboxes. I definitely need your help

Comment: as for your code - you do this `if (adapter.itemChecked[i]){...` but there's no code to set `itemChecked` array values. So these are always false

Comment: In general I see no use for this array. Remove it and make adapter's `isItemChecked()` method public and call it directly `if(adapter.isItemChecked(i)) {...`

Comment: Thanks again. It worked. I am new to java and so it took me lot of time to think about it. I have one more question related to this UI.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13284665/how-to-create-a-layout-as-in-the-in-figure-attached-supporting-multiple-selectio. can you please have a look at it